# setting up transparent proxy on gateway computer

Tags: vpn, proxy, router, transparent-proxy

I am looking to setup a transparent proxy (client) on a computer which will act as a gateway/router for (client) computers connecting to this gateway computer.  The client computers use a VPN client which is not going to be modified (nor will it have any proxy client).  The transparent proxy client will connect to a proxy (server) through which all traffic (including the VPN traffic) should be routed from.  Is this approach even possible with squid or ha proxy?

VPN client on computer -> transparent proxy on computer acting as router/gateway -> proxy on remote server -> VPN server  (and the traffic going back the same way).

Any thoughts or suggestions on this matter will be appreciated.

Comment: Tell us please what you have tried, currently, you are asking for a howto but this is not possible on server fault since this page handles businesses related issues. Did you google for howto set up squid as transparent proxy?

Comment: Not asking for a howto.  i need to know if this approach is even feasible (VPN client on computer connecting to transparent gateway on router)